# I cannot dynamically change language in Angular

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am trying to learn Angular and i18n concept. My xlf files are ok. My html files are ok (well... I think they are). I can choose a language through terminal like

```
ng serve --configuration=fr
```

but when I do that, only French version of the program works. I want to choose the language dynamically.

I am using Angular 8.

Comment: Please share a minimal representation of your implementation as well. It won't be possible to determine what's wrong without that. Or better, if possible, please provide a minimal reproducible [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) sample to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Original angular multilanguage support doesn't allow you to change language dynamically. The only thing you could do is to generate projects for different languages and implement language changing by means of your server.
You can read more about it here: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-the-completed-translation-file-into-the-app

If you want to be able to change language dynamically I'd advise you to use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate)

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this. Simple implementation is there. [Angular 8 translate with @ngx-translate](https://github.com/rajitharumesh/angular8translation)